# In Meteor, this.added and this.changed within observeChanges not functioning as expected

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm sorry for the vague title and the long post, but I'm having a hard time describing the behavior I'm getting. I'll try either way to explain.

I've got a newsfeed page where I'm displaying posts. I only want to display posts that are older than when the user opened up the page, so that the list stays reactive without adding new posts at the top. So I decided to use observeChanges within the publish function like this:

```
Newsfeed = new Mongo.Collection('newsfeed');

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish("newsfeed", function (init_last_activity, limit) {
        var self = this;

        check(limit, Number);
        check(init_last_activity, Date);

        var init = true,
            count = 0;

        var handle = Newsfeed.find({},{
            'limit': limit,
            'sort': {'updated_time': -1}
        }).observeChanges({
            // when a post is added, we check if it's got an older
            // updated_time than the initial updated time field
            // generated on init and only if so, we display
            // the post to the client
            added: function(id, doc) {
                count++;
                console.log('++++ POST NR. ' + count + ' ++++ ('+id+')');
                console.log('Updated time:  ', doc.updated_time);
                console.log('Last activity: ', init_last_activity);

                if (doc.updated_time < init_last_activity) {
                    console.log('- - - - -');
                    console.log('ADDED!');

                    self.added('newsfeed', id, doc);

                    console.log('ID: ' + id);
                    console.log(' ');
                }
            },

            changed: function(id, fields) {
                console.log('Trigger changed for id:', id);
                self.changed('newsfeed', id, fields);
            }
        });

        init = false;

        this.ready();

        this.onStop(function() {
            handle.stop();
        });
    });
}
```

Included are the console logs to illustrate that `self.added()` is actually being called. Here's the log for when a user refreshes the page:

```
I20141024-20:21:08.886(-7)? ++++ POST NR. 1 ++++ (9WMnDt5tJ6wePwfcs)
I20141024-20:21:08.887(-7)? Updated time:   Fri Oct 24 2014 20:17:47 GMT-0700 (PDT)
I20141024-20:21:08.887(-7)? Last activity:  Fri Oct 24 2014 20:21:08 GMT-0700 (PDT)
I20141024-20:21:08.887(-7)? - - - - -
I20141024-20:21:08.887(-7)? ADDED!
I20141024-20:21:08.887(-7)? ID: 9WMnDt5tJ6wePwfcs
I20141024-20:21:08.887(-7)?
I20141024-20:21:08.887(-7)? ++++ POST NR. 2 ++++ (7pt3nBKqgCKJ4G5fc)
I20141024-20:21:08.887(-7)? Updated time:   Fri Oct 24 2014 20:20:59 GMT-0700 (PDT)
I20141024-20:21:08.888(-7)? Last activity:  Fri Oct 24 2014 20:21:08 GMT-0700 (PDT)
I20141024-20:21:08.888(-7)? - - - - -
I20141024-20:21:08.888(-7)? ADDED!
I20141024-20:21:08.888(-7)? ID: 7pt3nBKqgCKJ4G5fc
I20141024-20:21:08.888(-7)?
```

As you can see, two posts were sent to the client. Now when the same user tries to 'like' the second post (`ID: 7pt3nBKqgCKJ4G5fc`), a few seconds later, which triggers `self.changed()` in the code above, this happens:

```
I20141024-20:21:13.997(-7)? Trigger changed for id: 7pt3nBKqgCKJ4G5fc
I20141024-20:21:13.997(-7)? Exception in queued task: Error: Could not find element with id 7pt3nBKqgCKJ4G5fc to change
I20141024-20:21:13.997(-7)?     at _.extend.changed (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:185)
I20141024-20:21:13.997(-7)?     at _.extend.changed (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:397)
I20141024-20:21:13.997(-7)?     at _.extend.changed (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1154)
I20141024-20:21:13.997(-7)?     at Newsfeed.find.observeChanges.changed (app/collections/newsfeed.js:125:22)
I20141024-20:21:13.998(-7)?     at packages/mongo/observe_multiplex.js:163
I20141024-20:21:13.998(-7)?     at Array.forEach (native)
I20141024-20:21:13.998(-7)?     at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:105)
I20141024-20:21:13.998(-7)?     at Object.task (packages/mongo/observe_multiplex.js:157)
I20141024-20:21:13.998(-7)?     at _.extend._run (packages/meteor/fiber_helpers.js:145)
I20141024-20:21:13.998(-7)?     at packages/meteor/fiber_helpers.js:123
```

The exact same id that was attached to the `self.added()` function a few seconds earlier. The weird part is that if I skip the if statement and just allow `self.added()` to run no matter what, everything works fine:

```
added: function(id, doc) {
    self.added('newsfeed', id, doc);
}
```

So, although `self.added()` is being called in the earlier example, it seems that just because it's being called within an if statement breaks the code.

Does anyone have any clue as to why this is happening? Am I misunderstanding the added and changed functions? I'm so confused :)

Comment: This is an old post, but I think I found a clue as to what's wrong over at this link: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1354 So for anyone who runs into this in the future, check out that link on GitHub.